# Changing the colour of slider ticks

Tags: java, slider, javafx-2

I'm attempting to change the colour of the ticks for a slider in JavaFX 2.2, but coming up a bit short - I can't find any [CSS properties on slider](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#slider) that claim to do this, and I can't find any [methods on Slider](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html) that seem to do this either (there seems to be a property for formatting the tick labels, but not the marks themselves.)

Is there a way, or am I stuck drawing it myself?

Comment: To better understand and find properties for styling standard JavaFX controls via css, refer to the source for the standard stylesheets ([modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) for newer styles or [caspian.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css) for older styles).  I find referring to these default stylesheets essential to understanding how to get the most out of JavaFX css.

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks, a good tip. I'll give that a read at some point!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this style description for ticks and blue color :

```
.slider .axis .axis-tick-mark, .slider .axis .axis-minor-tick-mark {
    -fx-fill: null;
    -fx-stroke: blue;
}
```

The first - for major, the second - for minor.

[image: slidertickcolors]

Comment: There was an issue about styling : https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19840.

Comment: Styling issue related to an older 2.1 branch of JavaFX and should not be present in recent production and development branches.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for - I somehow missed `axis-tick-mark`.