# JavaFX - Changing the colour of a sliders specific tick

Tags: java, css, javafx, slider

So i am going to add a password generator to my gui application, i want to add a slider to choose how secure the password is going to be. I can change the colour of all ticks, but i want to have red for the first, yellow for the second and green for the last tick.
This is the css code for changing the colour of all the major ticks. (Taken from [Changing the colour of slider ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341223/changing-the-colour-of-slider-ticks))

```
.slider .axis .axis-tick-mark {
    -fx-fill: null;
    -fx-stroke: red;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible.  Unless you implemented your own Slider control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, let's create a slider like you propose, with three major ticks:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Slider slider = new Slider(0, 10, 5);
    slider.setMajorTickUnit(5);
    slider.setMinorTickCount(0);
    slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
    slider.setSnapToTicks(true);
    StackPane root = new StackPane(slider);
    root.getStyleClass().add("pane");
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

where `style.css` contains:

```
.pane {
    -fx-background-color: #dcdcdc;
    -fx-padding: 10;
}

.slider .axis .axis-tick-mark {
    -fx-fill: null;
    -fx-stroke: red;
}
```

[image: no gradient]

Now let's check how the axis tick marks are created and what type of node they are. For that, you can choose any of these options:

- Have a look at the source code
- Use lookups
- Use [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/)

At this point `lookup` is faster. Add the call after the stage is shown:

```
primaryStage.show();

System.out.println("Axis-Tick-Mark: " + slider.lookup(".axis-tick-mark"));
```

and it will print out:

```
Axis-Tick-Mark: Path[elements=[MoveTo[x=0.0, y=0.0], LineTo[x=0.0, y=5.0], MoveTo[x=132.0, y=0.0], LineTo[x=132.0, y=5.0], MoveTo[x=264.0, y=0.0], LineTo[x=264.0, y=5.0]], fill=null, fillRule=NON_ZERO, stroke=0xff0000ff, strokeWidth=1.0]
```

And there you go, the axis tick mark is a [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Path.html), a single node. This means that you can't get any of the lines and style it differently.

But still, nothing prevents you from styling the path as *a whole*, if you modify the `stroke` property with a gradient.

So let's add a linear gradient, based on your colors:

```
.slider .axis .axis-tick-mark {
    -fx-fill: null;
    -fx-stroke-width: 2;
    -fx-stroke: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow, green);
}
```

That will work as expected:

[image: with gradient]

Obviously you can extend this to different setups (more than three ticks), vertical orientation, more or different colors...

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Wow! Beautiful answer.